# How to route request to codeigniter project outside document root

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, .htaccess

I have the following shared hosting file structure using a codeigniter project:

```
myTLD.com/sites/mysite

mysite contains: application, system , index.php ... ( standard CI2 setup )

myTLD.com/public_html - contains : index.php
```

I have symlinked  myTLD.com/public_html/index.php to  myTLD.com/sites/mysite/index.php

Unfortunately I am getting:

```
Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php
```

I have set it up this way to avoid placing the actual site in the document root for security purposes . I don't want to change mysite/index.php because I want to keep the entire project in its mysite directory where it can easily be revised etc.

The application and mysite/ folder are set to 755 so I don't think this is a permission problem .

My myTLD.com/public_html/.htaccess folder directs all requests to index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Can someone advise me on an approach to sending requests through to the codeigniter index file without causing this error?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried symlink for whole project directory?

Comment: could you explain what you mean?

Comment: It's common practice to put index.php in your public folder, and your system and application folders outside of the public root. "I don't want to change mysite/index.php because I want to keep the entire project in its mysite directory where it can easily be revised etc." That's a poor way of thinking. Chances are index.php will not need to be changed often, and your application logic is still kept separate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following way

1) Remove the symlink

2) Use this in htaccess at `myTLD.com/public_html/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myTLD.com/sites/mysite/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Use absolute system path if you are aware of it.